# Use 'HH:mm' string in moment js for add one hours (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have tested this code:

```
a = '10:10'
console.log( moment( a ).subtract(1, 'h').format('HH:mm'));
```

But it does not work, the output is:

```
Invalid date
```

Console error:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 10:10, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of time that you are providing to `moment`'s constructor is not understood by it. Please specify the time format as a second parameter and your code should run.

I'm guessing that the time format you are using is `HH:mm` meaning, hours in 24 hour format and minutes with a `:` in between.

```js
var a = '10:10'
var b = moment( a, 'HH:mm' ).subtract(1, 'h').format('HH:mm')
console.log(b);
alert(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Your date is not in a correct format. Try this

```
a = '2019-06-17 10:10:00'
console.log( moment( a ).subtract(1, 'h').format('HH:mm'));
```

[Sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/0x43czkp/)